# XSL - Grouping by list item column with multiple entries

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, xslt

I am attempting to utilize XSL to format results pulled from a document library, but unfortunately this is my first stab at XSL *ever*.
The columns in the document library are fairly standard - Title, Description - but also contain a custom column which contains a lookup to another list and it can contain multiple values (separated by semi-colons):

**DOCUMENT LIBRARY**

Image:
[image: Document library with roles]
The "Role" column is something I would like to use to 'group' the results.  Problem is, I am not sure how to query the document library in a fashion that if a document is part of multiple roles, then that document should appear under that 'heading'.

An example output I wish to attain:

[image: Roles]

Is this possible using XSL?  If so, what method would you recommend?  I can educate myself if I know what to search for :)  So if anyone knows of some keywords I should be googling for, please let me know!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This article on EndUserSharePoint explains how:

https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/pages/sharepoint-group-by-a-column-with-multiple-values.aspx

You basically need to create a linked data source to the lookup list and the main list with the join option.