# Change Header on Group By

Tags: list, xslt, grouping, sorting

Suppose I have a SharePoint list with a choice column "Department".  Department has the following choices:
Executive, Admin, Sales, Accounting, IT

I want to do a group by on this column, but the headers get sorted alphabetically, like so:

- Accounting

  - Entries
- Admin

  - Entries

and so on.

I would like to sort the groups on a different column (DepartmentSort), to keep them in the above order

- Executive

  - Entries
- Admin

  - Entries

and so on.

I know I could make the entries "1. Executive", "2. Admin", "3. Sales", but I am trying to not do this.

My searching on this topic points to XSLT, but I have to admit, I'm quite lost.

Comment: I think there is a similar post to this in SharePoint Stackexchange. Check this link http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/61752/xsl-grouping-by-list-item-column-with-multiple-entries

Comment: This is similar, but not the same.  That is grouping by multiple columns.  I would like to group by one column, but use a different column as the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a warning.  You can not use JavaScript after the page is rendered to change the field as it will break the grouping function in the default list view.

Two good choices:

1. Use SharePoint Designer and edit the XSL directly to change the text values.
2. Use JavaScript/HTML and recreate your own your list and get full control of how it is displayed.  I would look at using [SPServices()](http://spservices.codeplex.com/) for pulling in the data and maybe one of the JQuery plug-ins for dynamic tables.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this, using Jesus Shelby's first suggestion.  Tedious, but it works.  Details:

Assumptions: I have a list with two columns, Header, and HeaderSort.  I want to sort the groups by HeaderSort, but display Header as the group title.

Steps:

- Add a Data View Web Part, tied to the list in question.  Columns (except group title and group sort columns) are added to the view.
- Configure grouping to group by the group sort column
- Switch to split view (code and design) for ease of editing
- Select the group title (i.e., the Header Sort column name for the first group)
- Change the xsl:value-of tag to just the desired group title (static rather than dynamic)
- Select the group value (i.e., the Header Sort value for the first group)
- change the xsl:value-of tag to equal @HeaderTitle column instead of $fieldvalue

Tedious to do for each view rather than having a built-in way, but it works.

Accepted Jesus Shelby's answer because its the most right solution that isnt my answer.