# Is there a way to hide/remove "group by field name text" in group by filter view in both modern/classic views SPOnline?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, modern-experience

In SPOnline site, One of my document library's field name is called "Category". On the view it is showing as "Category:Finance(2)". My client doesn't want this text("Cateory:") .It seems like an OOB behaviour in SPOnline. But is there a way I can hide/remove this text in Both Modern/Classic Views ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For modern view, i don't think you can hide that group by name. For classic view, you can use SharePoint Designer to change the XSL or use JavaScript/HTML and recreate your own your list and get full control of how it is displayed.

Similar thread:[Change Header on Group By](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/78958/change-header-on-group-by)

You can vote in UserVoice for this feature:https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/33600652-hide-grouped-by-column-name

Comment: Thanks for your answer and I have voted on the uservoice  as well.

Comment: @devsiva Glad to be help. You can mark the reply as answer if you feel it helpful